# Write a procedure to check whether rows exists for each comma separated value or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below code works for only in value. But I wanted to check with other values too that whether row exists or not.

```
 IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.Params where Value in ('Z111'))
    BEGIN
        Print 'True';
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    Print 'False';
       -- INSERT HERE
    END
```

Suppose I am checking with two different values i.e. 'Z111' and 'P111'. For one value no row is present in the table and for other value is present. How to differentiate. Actually I want to insert value for those whose entry is not present.

```
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.Params where Value in ('Z111,P111'))
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sql server management 2017

Comment: It's not the version of SSMS that matters, but the version of SQL Server it's connecting to. Which is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `STRING_SPLIT`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Params(Value)
SELECT Value
FROM string_split('Z111,P111',',') as MV
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Params p WHERE p.Value = MV.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition works fine; you just don't understand the difference between a single string value that has a comma and multiple values.  The logic you want is best written as:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.Params where Value in ('Z111', 'P111'))
```

If this is being passed in as a value, you can either split the string:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.Params where Value in (select value from string_split(@param))
```

Or use `LIKE`:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.Params where ',' + @param + ',' LIKE '%,' + Value + ',%')
```